# How do I permanently change the background color of a row in a Listview?

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I want to change the background color of a row in my listview. Right now I'm doing this with

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                int position, long id) {


        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));//                

        }
```

Which works - but when I scroll down on my listview so that the row with the changed background color is out of sight, and then scroll back up, the row no longer has a changed color.

Is there a way that I can permanently set the background color of a row so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: You'd have to implement a custom listview adapter of your own where your listview class has a boolean if it's selected then manage the background color in the `getView` function of your custom list view adapter. This way, you have a better way of tracking which element is selected.

Comment: I am guessing that your `View` is recycled/state cleared once it leaves the viewable screen. You would need to save state in some sort of data model or the view tag for the selected items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to make a Custom `ListView` with your own `row_layout.xml` file, a `CustomListViewObject` that has a `boolean` to check if the element is clicked or not, and lastly, a `CustomListView` to check if the row element is selected or not.

Your row layout `row_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textfield"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how your row class should look like:

```
public class CustomRowClass {

    private String input;
    private boolean selected;

    public BallotEntryClass() {
    }

    public BallotEntryClass(String input, boolean selected) {
        this.input = input;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    //setters and getters here
}
```

And finally, your adapter:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<CustomRowClass> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapterBallot(Context context, ArrayList<CustomRowClass> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.input = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textfield);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textfield.setText(listData.get(position).getInput());

        //check here if state = 1 which means selected state
        if(listData.get(position).isSelected()){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else{
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView input;
    }
}
```

And that's it. To use this, do it as such:

```
ListView sampleListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

//create your listView with your custom object
ArrayList<CustomRowClass> data = new ArrayList<>();


for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++){
    CustomRowClass entry = new CustomRowClass("Name " + i, false);
    data.add(entry);
}

//create your adapter, use the nameAndAgeList ArrayList
CustomListViewAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, data);

//get your listView and use your adapter
listView.setAdapter(sampleListView);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CustomRowClass selection = (CustomRowClass) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        selection.setSelected(true);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: That makes sense, and it worked! Thanks a ton man! Now I actually might be able to grab a few hours of sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Define an adapter for your listView,save the index value of which item is clicked in memory,and use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to redraw the views when clicked,set the background color according to the index value.

Here's some sample codes may help you.I just write the java codes and have no time to finish xml files and write test data to test.So if there's a problem in this code,please tell me.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
  ListView listView;
  ArrayList<String> dataList;
  int selectedIndex=-1;
  TestAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

    //init your dataList here
    adapter=new TestAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedIndex=position;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}




public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        LinearLayout background;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(null==dataList){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return dataList.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(null==convertView){
            convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_test,null);
            ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.background=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.background);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        String data=dataList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(data);
        if(position == selectedIndex){
            holder.background.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }else{
            holder.background.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}

}
```